# which types require using JDO dependent="true" for cascading deletes?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm using the JDO annotation dependent="true" to delete my owned child classes like this:

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "parent")
@Order(column="PARENT_CHILD_IDX")
@Element( dependent="true" )    
private ArrayList< Child> children = new ArrayList< Child >();
```

Do I need to do this for other non-custom data types like Long, String, Link, Blob, and Text? enums?

```
    @Persistent( defaultFetchGroup="true", dependant="true" )
    private Text veryLongString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on the appengine-java group and the response is:

```
 If you delete an entity, Text and Blob properties in that entity will be deleted as well.
```